# Assume $x,y \in F$ and F is an ordered field, if $x<0$ and $y<0$, then $xy>0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, inequality, proof-explanation, solution-verification, ordered-fields

I was thinking since $x<0$ and $y<0$, $-x>0$ and -y<0 by adding the additive inverse. Then we multiply -x and -y to get $(-x)(-y)>0$ since $-x>0$ and $-y>0$, but I feel like this is wrong.

Is it $x=-x$ and $y=-y$ since $x<0$ and $y<0$? If so, why? Can someone help me, please?

Comment: You need to show that $-x=(-1)x$. Then it will reduce to showing that $(-1)(-1)=1$. Can you put these pieces together?

Comment: @TedShifrin Does $-x=(-1)x$ and $-y=(-1)y$ by the mulitplicative identity, then multiply these to get $(-1)x(-1)y=(-1)^2xy=1xy=xy$?

Comment: By the multiplicative identity? I don’t follow. As a hint, I will tell you that you will need to use the distributive property and the definition of additive inverse.

Answer (score 1):

By your work $$(-x)(-y)+(-x)y>(-x)y,$$ which gives $$(-x)y<0$$ and from here
$$(-x)y+xy<xy,$$ which gives $$xy>0.$$
We used that $0x=0,$ which I hope you can prove.